# How to substitute newlines that ends with * (asterisk)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Good day,

I was wondering how to do a substitution with `*`.

The Input:

```
"Table: 1.1.3 Nivel de Formacion: *
Seleccione el maximo nivel de formacion que usted ha alcanzado hasta el momento * Departamento - ."
```

The output that I want:

```
"Table: 1.1.3 Nivel de Formacion: Seleccione el maximo nivel de formacion que usted ha alcanzado hasta el momento * Departamento - ."
```

The substitution:

```
sed 's/ \*\n/ /g'
```

or

```
awk '{ sub(/ \*\n/, ""); print }'
```

And nothing has worked, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\*\n//g'
```

Comment: Because Perl reads in the whole line with the newline character, and removing that will cause the newline not to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS=' \\*\n' -v ORS= '1' file
"Table: 1.1.3 Nivel de Formacion: Seleccione el maximo nivel de formacion que usted ha alcanzado hasta el momento Departamento - ."
```

What you were trying doesn't work because sed always reads 1 line at a time and awk reads 1 line at a time by default so in both cases the terminating `\n` from the end of each line was already consumed by the tool before you tried to replace it with your RE.

Answer (score 1):

**sed**:

```
sed -r '{s/ \*$/ /; T; N; s/\n// }' file
```

**awk**:

```
awk '
  / \*$/ { sub(/\*$/,""); printf("%s", $0); next }
  1
' file
```

Comment: work in limited case of maximum 2 lines (like in sample request but request does not limit to 2 lines)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/\*$/{N;s/\*\n//;}' file
```

Since `*` is a meta character we need to escape it to allow `sed` to learn that it needs to be considered a literal character.

We put that condition for our `sed` to look for lines that end with `*` and if we find such line, we execute a block which states append the next line to pattern space and then substitute the `*\n` with nothing.